# Python check if user is NOT in database

Tags: python, database

So I have 3 def tests (test1,test2 and test3) below, I am focusing on def test3, where, I want to be able to check if a user **IS NOT** in the database, does anybody know how I would go about doing that?

Code:

```
   '''
security service tests
'''
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import requests
import json
from common.constants import *
from config.settings import environment


security_environment = environment()['security_service']
service_url = "%s://%s:%d" % (
    security_environment['protocol'], 
    security_environment['host'], 
    security_environment['port'])


def test1():
  print "TEST 1 - get user details"
  headers     = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
  url         = "%s/user/1" % service_url
  response    = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  status_code = response.status_code
  print "STATUS: %s" % status_code
  print "DATA:   %s" % response.json()
  return status_code == HTTP_OK


def test2():
  print "TEST 2 - Count amount of Users"
  headers     = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
  url         = "%s/users" % service_url
  response    = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  status_code = response.status_code
  data = response.json()
  print (len(data))

  if status_code != HTTP_OK:
    return False
  return len(data) == 5


def test3():
  print "TEST 3 - Check if user is NOT in the Database"
  headers     = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
  url         = "%s/users" % service_url
  response    = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  status_code = response.status_code
  users = response.json()

  if users is None:
    status_code != HTTP_OK

  else:
    status_code == HTTP_OK



if __name__ == "__main__":
  num_pass = 0
  num_fail = 0

  for test in [test1, test2, test3]:
    print "-----------------------------------------------------------"

    if test():
      num_pass += 1
      print "PASS"
    else:
      num_fail += 1
      print "FAIL"

  print "==========================================================="
  print "%d passed, %d failed" % (num_pass, num_fail)
```

Comment: What's the problem with your existing code?

Comment: nothing wrong with it.Just in def test3() i am trying to check if a user is in the  database or not and i cant get it to work

Comment: What database? You don't seem to have any code dealing with a database here.

Comment: @julio, you mean that it returns a wrong answer every time, or some other error?

Comment: What's `echo` doing in your python code? Did you paste that block in from another language?

Comment: @khelwood: `echo` and `in_array` seem to be PHP.

Comment: sorry im clueless in this part of the code, this is why i asked for help. im importing a array of users (5 in this case), I have changed def test2() see code below:

Comment: def test2():
  print "TEST 2 - Count amount of Users"
  headers     = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
  url         = "%s/users" % service_url
  response    = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  status_code = response.status_code
  data = response.json()
  print (len(data))
  
  if status_code != HTTP_OK:
    return False
  return len(data) == 5

Comment: I need to do the inverse of this code to check if User is NOT there

Answer (score 0):

Give us sample of your response.

If your json data looks like this one:

```
objUser = [{'login': 'monkey1', 'name': 'Adam'},
           {'login': 'monkey2', 'name': 'Maria'}]
```

Try somting like this:

```
def test3(user):
    print "TEST 3 - Check if user is NOT in the Database"
    headers     = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
    url         = "%s/users" % service_url
    response    = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    status_code = response.status_code
    if status_code == 200:
        print 'Status: OK'

        # json() method return False if no json in respone 
        users = response.json()
        if users:
            # covert json string to python object
            objUsers = json.loads(users)

            # iter users collection
            result = [u['login'] for u in objUsers if u['login'] == user]

            # if result empty return true, user IS NOT in reponse
            if result:
                return False
            else:
                return True

        else:
            print 'No json data in response.'

    else:
        print 'Couldn\'t get response from server.'
```